# rails require_tree and javascript is not working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, erb

My javascripts are not working when i have `= require_tree .` inside my application.js, if i delete it then my js.erb for a view `some_view.js.erb` is not working.

My application.js file:

```
/*
 = require jquery
 = require jquery_ujs
 = require jquery-1.7.1.min
 = require jquery.validate.min
 = require jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min
 = require jquery.cookie
 = require_self
 = require_tree .
 */
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

The correct manifest file format for the `application.js` file looks like this:

```
 //= require_self
 //= require jquery
 //= require jquery_ujs
 //= require jquery.validate.min
 //= require jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min
 //= require jquery.cookie
 //= require_tree .
```

Comment: I tried both way, result is the same. Maybe the problem is that i have couple jquery version inside javascript directory?

Comment: You can try to move `require_self` on top of the statements. I think you should leave just `//require jquery`, it will be the version of your `jquery-rails` gem.